# Metadata API for Google MCF Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics-api

If there a similar meta data API for MCF reporting like there is for GA:
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/metadata/ga/columns?pp=1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No currently the [Google Analytics Metadata api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/) only supports the Normal [Core reporting dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).

But if you check the documentation for [columns list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/reference/metadata/columns/list) there is a parameter option.  It currently states.

> reportType string Report type. Allowed Values: ga. Where ga
>   corresponds to the Core Reporting API.

Right now the only thing you can request are the ga dimensions and metrics but this implies to me that they may at some point open up for more.

I added a feature request a while back asking for [Access to Realtime Dimensions and metric list](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=419&q=metadata&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary).   I have asked the devs and the only response was they weren't going to do it right now.